# How to solve connection isuse

Tags: sql-server-2008

Connection problem error message:

```
 NHibernate.ADOException: cannot open connection ---> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'view5service'.
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "VMwareView5" requested by the login. The login failed.
ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'view5service'.
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "VMwareView5" requested by the login. The login failed.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenConnection()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenConnection()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at VMware.Sim.ServiceCore.Persistence.Database.SimDbTransaction.Begin(Nullable`1 isolationLevel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 1):

`Login failed for user 'view5service'` would be the issue.

Check the password for the account, make sure you can connect to the database and have the correct rights as that user.